# The resource cannot be found - User Control in a MasterPage

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, user-controls

I wanted to add a user control to a MasterPage. I added the control to a VS Solution and deployed it. Then I opened the MasterPage via SharePoint Designer and added the following code:

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc0" TagName="LanguageChecker" Src="~/_controltemplates/Project/UserControls/LanguageChecker.ascx" %>`

Now when I open a page that uses this .master I get the following error:

> Server Error. The resource cannot be found.

When I looked at the page sorce it said:

> The file `/_controltemplates/Project/UserControls/LanguageChecker.ascx
>   does not exist.`

Of course it doesn't. The file path is missing the Site Url in the beginning.

I looked and found some possible problems. The only one that caught my attention was: SharePoint Designer might remove the "~/" from registration of the User Control in the master. I opened the designer again but the ~/ is there. I want to see the file itself, to check if the ~/ exists in it.

However the MasterPage has been added via the SharePoint Designer and I do not know where to look for the actual file. Is it on the Hard Drive?

I tryed to find the user control by it's Url(full, correct) and it's there.

I am using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

If this is 2013 the path should be:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc0" TagName="LanguageChecker" Src="/_controltemplates/15/Project/UserControls/LanguageChecker.ascx" %>
```

So, remove the `~` and add /15 to the Src.

Your user control should be added to the Mapped folder CONTROLTEMPLATES in VS